# Child div height determines parent height?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a parent div that contains two children, side by side. The first child is an image that must be height 100% and 58% width, margin auto and overflow hidden. The second child contains text, and the length of the text determines the height of the parent. This is a template for several pages, with different length of text, and therefore different parent height. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do without using JS? Thanks for your input! Code below.

HTML:

```
<div id="product-summary">

  <div class="product-image-container">
    <img />
  </div>

  <div id="product-details">
    <h3 class="product-title"></h3>
    <div class="product-description"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

#product-details {
  float: right;
  border: solid thin #777;
  height: ~"calc(100% - 2px)";
  width: 41%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Provide some JSfiddle/similar code.

Comment: Thanks, added code

Comment: You can set an image as a background of 1st child, so it won't affects on height of parent div

Comment: @j08691 It is LESS code, and the code is working fine currently, but i am seeking a better conceptual solution

Comment: @Banzay Thanks, i like this suggestion. I'm not sure it is possible due to the platform i'm building on (Squarespace), but I will investigate. Still open to other solutions!

Comment: Ah I didn't see you added that tag when you added your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your #product-details is floated, which creates a new BFM (block formatting context), and the parent gets collapsed.

I suggest you read more about BFMs here: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/

There are several ways to fix this:

- You could clear the parent, a way to do that is by adding overflow: hidden; to the #product-summary element.
- You could remove the float: right from #product-details, and use flexbox to align it instead.

Comment: This guy is a genius

Comment: Wow this is perfect, your first suggestion is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any preprocessor wizardry, but using `inline-block` works good, as well as keeping `positioned absolute` elements wrapped in a `relative` parent for control. It wasn't mentioned how the image is displayed, so I assume aspect ratio unchanged and no cropping.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.product-image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 58%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#product-details {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: 100%;
  width: 41%;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-summary">

  <div class="product-image-container">
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
  </div>

  <div id="product-details">
    <h3 class="product-title">Lena Söderberg</h3>
    <div class="product-description">
      <blockquote>Lenna or Lena is the name given to a standard test image widely used in the field of image processing since 1973. It is a picture of Lena Söderberg, shot by photographer Dwight Hooker, cropped from the centerfold of the November 1972 issue of Playboy
        magazine.
      </blockquote>
      <a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna'>Wikipedia</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```